# Finding Prescribed Neighborhood on a Manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Given a smooth manifold, prove that for an open set $U\subset M$ we can always find a closed set $\bar{B}\subset U$ such that $B$ is a neighborhood of some point $p\in U$.

My attempt: since $M$ has basis of regular balls, there exists $B\subset U$  which is regular ball, so exist another $B'$ such that $\bar{B}\subset B'$. But how to show it is contained in $U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $p\in U$ and choose a coordinate ball $V\ni p$ with $V\subseteq U$. We can choose this ball so that there is a diffeomorphism $\phi:V\to B_r(0)\subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$.Then, set $W=\phi^{-1}(B_{r/2}(0))$, and then note that $\overline{W}\subseteq U$ and that $W$ is a neighborhood of $p$.

Note: the first choice of $V$ is possible because there is a basis by coordinate open sets.

Comment: Thanks,I have a similar idea, since the basis for manifold is actually the inverse image of ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with rational radius, and they are very dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$